# Sensitivity and stability of the LDA models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, lda

I used an LDA over a corpus of 60000 entries and I got a good result. But inserting 200 more lines in this corpus and relaunching the LDA, I have quite different topics. However, 200 lines do not represent 1% of the corpus. Normally, the results should not change. I've looked for something about the sensitivity and stability of the LDA models and I've seen that they're just pretty sensitive on the parameter level ... does anyone know anything about this?

Here this script:

```
import pandas
import mglearn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

text = pandas.read_csv('pretraitement_janaina_modif.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
text_list = text.values.tolist()

vector = CountVectorizer()
X = vector.fit_transform(text_list)

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components = 30, learning_method = "batch", max_iter = 25, random_state = 0)
document_topics = lda_model.fit_transform(X)
sorting = np.argsort(lda_model.components_, axis = 1)[:, ::-1]
feature_names = np.array(vector.get_feature_names())

topics = mglearn.tools.print_topics(topics = range(30), feature_names = feature_names, sorting = sorting, topics_per_chunk = 5, n_words = 10)

print(topics)
```

**I have as a first result this list of topics:**

> Topic 0: no order mail received back always share refund answer more
>
> Topic 1: cancel order wishes possible wish would wish to advance error items deceived
>
> Topic 2: keep current informed delivery order informed product inform face number
>
> Topic 3: faulty wooden box present box side level painting defects box

**But when I add some few lines in the corpus, the topics change:**

> Topic 0: big top metal big size damaged product chandelier canape support
>
> Topic 1: receipt ordered article product misses well order not send back only
>
> Topic 2: faulty wooden box present box side level painting defects box
>
> Topic 3: order payment amount spend transfer made pay bank come well

What I don't understand is how this algorithm can be so sensitive and not stability and change so much when we add a few lines...

Comment: What do you mean by `"have quite different topics"`? Show the code of what you did

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks so much, I add the code but I think this is not the most important... maybe LDA isn't stability and so sensitive... and this is my question.

Comment: You printed 4 topics, but how many topics did your model produce? If you have more than 4 topics in your LDA model, my guess is that they have just been shuffled around. There is no meaning attached to being 'Topic 0' or 'Topic K' and usually when you re-run your model, the order of the topics is randomly shuffled

Comment: @KenHBS Not really. If you run the same text with the same parameters you will always have the same topics in the same order...